# Loop through array in Twig

Tags: theming, 8

I have this array

```
{% set icons = { 1: 'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk', 
                 2: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus', 
                 3: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus',
                 4: 'glyphicon glyphicon-euro'   
                 } 
%}
```

I want to loop through it and print like this

```
<li{{ item.attributes.addClass('pos' ~ loop.index, icons[loop.index]) }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

**Twig:**

```
<ul>
  {% for key, icon in icons %}
    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('pos' ~ key, icon) }}>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Source:**
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html